# How to move a record in list based on picklist value selected in VF Page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, actionsupport

I have a VF page in that I am having a List which has picklist field called "Status", values named "open" and "complete". When we select the  picklist value "Complete" then the record should move to the another list called "history" which empty by initial. Kindly tell how to get the picklist value.Thanks in advanced

Code:

```
public with sharing class sample {
    public Integer numberOfRowToRemove1 { get; set; }
    public List<Account> list1 { get; set; }
    public List<Account> list2 { get; set; }
    public string temp{get;set;}

    public sample() {
        list1 = [select id,name,accountnumber from Account limit 2];
        list2 = [select id,name,accountnumber from Account limit 3];
    }

    public List<selectOption> getitems() {
        List<selectoption> options=new List<selectoption>();
        options.add(new selectoption('Complete','Complete'));
        options.add(new selectoption('Open','Open'));
        return options;
    }

    public PageReference showdata() {
        if(temp=='Complete') {
            list2.add(0,list1.get(numberOfRowToRemove1));
            list1.remove(numberOfRowToRemove1);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="sample" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="rowNumber1" />
        <apex:outputPanel id="panelWithVar">
            <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="rowNumber1" />
        </apex:outputPanel>
        **<apex:actionFunction name="find" action="{!showdata}"/>**  

        <apex:pageBlock id="table1">
            <apex:dataTable value="{!list1}" var="a" columnswidth="100px,100px" cellpadding="3" columns="4" border="1" width="500px" bgcolor="#f5dcef" rowClasses="1" >
                <apex:column value="{!a.Name}" headerValue="Customer Name" />
                <apex:column value="{!a.AccountNumber}" headerValue="Number" width="100"/>
                <apex:column headerClass="Status">
                    **<apex:selectList id="selected_list" value="{!temp}" required="false" size="1" onchange="find();">**
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
                        <!--<apex:selectOption itemvalue="None" itemLabel="--None--"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemvalue="complete" itemLabel="complete"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemvalue="Open" itemLabel="Open"/>-->
                        <!--<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="Details,panelWithVar,table1" action="{!find}" onsubmit="checkAll(this)"/>-->
                        <apex:param name="p1" value="{!rowNumber1}" assignTo="{!numberOfRowToRemove1}"/>
                    </apex:selectList>
                    <apex:variable var="rowNumber3" value="{!rowNumber1 + 1}" />
                </apex:column>
            </apex:dataTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageBlock id="Details">
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:panelGroup >
                    <apex:dataTable value="{!list2}" var="a" columnswidth="50px,50px" cellpadding="4" border="1" >
                        <apex:column value="{!a.Name}" headerValue="Customer Name" width="100"/>
                        <apex:column value="{!a.AccountNumber}" headerValue="Address" width="100"/>
                        <apex:column headerClass="Status">
                            <apex:selectList id="selected_list" value="{!temp}" required="false" size="1">

                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
                            </apex:selectList>
                        </apex:column>
                    </apex:dataTable>
                </apex:panelGroup>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: @Mohith ,Thanks I have updated my question. I have tried this but its not working

Comment: I think you should use action function and on change of picklist call the pagereference method and in page reference method manage your list .

Comment: @MohithKumar Thanks a lot for your reply, I have done this <apex:actionFunction  reRender="Details,panelWithVar,table1" action="{!find}" onsubmit="checkAll(this)"/> . But its not working please give some clarification on this.

Comment: i dont see pagereference method and also not sure whats temp varibale?The variable has to be for each record and your select option picker should itself get set before your action method and you can use that

Comment: @MohithKumar thanks for the reply. I have updated my question , but its not working. Please check this and guide me.

Comment: @LavanyaSanathkumar I have logic I can share if you want a custom multipick list. Would this suffice for resolving your issue?

Answer (score 1):

It might help you a bit if you understood more of what you're actually doing with your `controller` and the `visual force` page it's intended to work with. It appears that you're creating a `controller` to report and change the `Status` of something related to an `Account`. That could be any number of things, but in this case, I suspect it's used for `Tasks` (sorry, but your code doesn't tell us the actual use case, so am guessing here).

This `controller` could be used for a page inserted as a `related list` on another page that reports on `Opportunities`. When the status of the `Task` changes from `Open` to `Closed`, the record would then need to be added to the `History` for the `Opportunity` its related to. When that happens, the list for `History` within your `controller` needs to be updated or refreshed. One doesn't "move" the record from one list to the another. Instead, the `Task record` is updated and the `controller's contents` are then refreshed when the page is updated using the `action method` that calls for a `rerender`.

Mohith has given you excellent assistance on how to resolve your coding issues with the controller, but I thought it might be helpful to you to explain a bit more about what was also going on that wasn't quite as evident based on the description you were providing of what you wanted the controller to do for you.

Answer (score 1):

Go through this code :)
Similar problem statement to move records from one pageblocktable to another :)

Controller :

```
public class SampleSE
{

    public List<cAccount> accountList {get;set;}

    public List<Account> selectedAccounts{get;set;}

    public Integer value {get;set;}

    public List<cAccount> getAccounts()
    {
        if(accountList == null)
        {
            accountList = new List<cAccount>();
            for(Account a : [select Id, Name, Phone from Account limit 10])
            {
                accountList.add(new cAccount(a));
            }
        }
        return accountList;
    }
    public PageReference processSelected()
    {
        selectedAccounts = new List<Account>();
        for(cAccount aAcc : getAccounts())
        {
            if(aAcc.selected == true)
            {
            selectedAccounts.add(aAcc.acc);

            }

        }
        value = selectedAccounts.size();

        return null;
    }
    public List<Account> getSelectedAccounts()
    {
        if(selectedAccounts.size()>0)
            return selectedAccounts;
        else
            return null;
    }
    public class cAccount
    {
        public Account acc {get; set;}
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}
        public cAccount(Account a) {
            acc = a;
            selected = false;
        }
    }//Wrapper Class
}
```

Visualforce Page :

```
<apex:page controller="sampleSE" >
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Move Selected" action="{!processSelected}" rerender="test"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Accounts}" var="a" >
            <apex:column >
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.selected}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!a.acc.Name}" />
            <apex:column value="{!a.acc.Phone}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:pageBlock id="test">
        Total No of Selected Records :<apex:outputText value="{!value }"/>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!SelectedAccounts}" var="a" >
            <apex:column value="{!a.Name}" />
            <apex:column value="{!a.Phone}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a problem in the reRender of the action function find, because you are only rendering the new list and you need rerender the 2 list.

Can you try this?

```
<apex:actionFunction name="find" action="{!showdata}" reRender="table1,Details"/>**
```

Regards